# How to compare every value in JSON response and filter them based on some condition in python?

Tags: python

I have a JSON response which looks like this

```
response = {
   "detections":[
      {
         "label":"apple",
         "x":50,
      },
      {
         "label":"apple",
         "x":55,
      },
      {
         "label":"apple",
         "x":500,
      },
      {
         "label":"banana",
         "x":352,
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to filter this response such that, the values where the labels are same filter out if the absolute difference between them is less than 10, otherwise keep both the responses

So I want the final result to be like this

```
updated_response = {
             "detections":[
                {
                   "label":"apple",
                   "x":50,
                },
                {
                   "label":"apple",
                   "x":500,
                },
                {
                   "label":"banana",
                    "x":352,
                }
             ]
          }
```

The second value where x=55 is removed because the absolute difference between them is less than 10, but third value with x=500 is included because the absolute difference is more than 10

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Difference between adjacent items?  Because apple.50 is > 10 from apple.500.  what if there are bananas between apples?  Is this list sorted?  if so, by what? and why do you keep the solo banana?

Comment: How is this different than it would be if you just had Python literal data that had never been encoded as JSON in the first place? If it's not different, why is JSON a part of the question?

Comment: The response is not sorted, its returned randomly. The banana is a single value, if there was another value with label banana and the difference between them was less than 10 then one of them should be removed

Comment: May you answer @Jl Peyret 's question, I'd like to know too.

Comment: I'm guessing that what you want is to effectively group the items by label and then sort by x so that the initial order doesn't matter.  If you have two items with values that are close enough together to want to remove one of them, then you want to always remove the one with the higher x value?

Comment: yes, exactly. If the value of x are less than the threshold group them, otherwise keep both of them. The order does not matter. If the values are close discard one keep the other, any one of them can be included, no condition on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my take on your solution, not trying to use any fancy list comprehensions or trying to limit the number of lines I use, but instead keeping things simple and hopefully easy to understand:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

response = {
   "detections":[
      {
         "label":"apple",
         "x":50,
      },
      {
         "label":"apple",
         "x":55,
      },
      {
         "label":"apple",
         "x":500,
      },
      {
         "label":"banana",
         "x":352,
      }
   ]
}

# Build a dictionary where the keys are labels and the values
# are lists with the x values for that label
labels = defaultdict(list)
for item in response['detections']:
    label = item['label']
    x = item['x']
    labels[label].append(x)

# Sort each of the lists (the values) in the dictionary we created
for label in labels:
    labels[label] = sorted(labels[label])

# Now for each of the labels in our dictionary...
for label in labels:
    # Get a reference to the list of 'x' values for this label
    l = labels[label]
    # Walk backwards across the list of label 'x' values...
    for i in range(len(l)-1, 0, -1):
        # If the current value is 10 units or less from the next (prior?) value,
        # then remove the current value
        if l[i] - l[i-1] <= 10:
            del l[i]

# Now create a list of items that looks like the list in original data
r = []
for label in labels:
    for x in labels[label]:
        r.append({"label": label, "x": x})

# Wrap the list in a dictionary like in the original data
updated_response = {'detections':r}

# Show the resulting dictionary as pretty JSON
print(json.dumps(updated_response, indent=4))
```

Result:

```
{
    "detections": [
        {
            "label": "apple",
            "x": 50
        },
        {
            "label": "apple",
            "x": 500
        },
        {
            "label": "banana",
            "x": 352
        }
    ]
}
```

I think the only slightly clever thing here is to walk each list backwards when doing the deletion.  This is a common trick to use when you'll be deleting items. It basically means that the location of any item will only change after it's been considered. Walking through the list in the forward direction isn't as easy.

Comment: This will work but I want the response in the exact format as I mentioned above

Comment: Thanks man, this is perfect. I know I didn't ask the question properly, but you got what I was trying to achieve. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know if you want to include or exclude an item that is exactly 10 units away from the prior item.  The way you word your question, it's ambiguous, because you say "less than 10" and "more than 10".

Comment: Glad I could help!